# How can I do array_push in validation array on Laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I know laravel validation write with arrays like this.

```
'test' => [
              'integer',
              'min:1',
          ],
```

That arrays can write as same as this.

```
'test' => 'integer|min:1',
```

So, My question is how can I insert valiable on validation array?

That is able to write if validation one-line like this.

```
if(Input::get('test1') == Input::get('test2')){
     $test = 'required';
}
else {
     $test = '';
}

'test' => 'integer|min:1|' . $test,
```

Also can write on array like this.

```
if(Input::get('test1') == Input::get('test2')){
     $test = [
                 'integer',
                 'min:1',
                 'required',
             ];
}
else {
     $test = [
                 'integer',
                 'min:1',
             ];
}

'test' => $test,
```

But I dont wanna write like above Cuz My validation is very long but wanna push string is just 1.

So I wish to use like push_array...

```
if(Input::get('test1') == Input::get('test2')){
     $test = 'required',
}
else {
     $test = '',
}

'test' => [
              'integer',
              'min:1',
              "$test",
          ],
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: try with `array_prepend()` function ....

Comment: Thanks reply. Yes It's truly work as same as below. And readable. But Today I choose another one that a bit of lesser number. Next time I try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$test = ['integer','min:1'];
if(Input::get('test1') == Input::get('test2')){
   $test[] = 'required';
}
```

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeetttttttttttt!!!!!!!!!! Yeah That's it!!!!!! Thank you every time. You save my code 400 to 50. Read as easy as pie. Terima kasih ;D